# Which is correct? "Sa'ei Park" or "Park Sa'ei"?

Tags: grammar

Sa'ei is the name of a park. Like Everest, which is referred to as Mount Everest, can we say also "Park Sa'ei" or should we say "Sa'ei Park"? This has become confusing to me as I see both usages of similar combinations in different contexts and wonder which is correct or preferable. Another examples are library and street names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the specific example of *mount name* is probably more closely derived from the French rather than English usage.
Mont Blanc etc is a close comparison to Mount Everest.

There are many 'mountain' examples that use the standard English structure of *name mountain* rather than *mount name* - among them Table Mountain, Red Mountain, Split Mountain.

If you look at this list of [mountain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountains), it seems that there are relatively few called *name mountain* & quite a lot more with *mount name*  & a considerable number that would appear to have either no specific designation, or something other, like peak.

Anyway, back to your original question - because English usually forms as *name description* it would invariably be "Sa'ei Park" & similarly 'Sa'ei Library', 'Sa'ei street/road/avenue' etc.

To stretch the comparison, in the same way we would always say 'red car' to mean the car which is red, we would use 'Sa'ei Park', in effect, as 'the park in [or named after] Sa'ei'.